# How to show drop-down content on hover or on click?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, dropdown

How do I hide the drop-down button to the hover or click to display it? I specifically use foundation zurb plugin. Look my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu" data-drilldown data-back-button='<li class="js- 
 drilldown- 
back"><a class="new-back"></a></li>'style="width: 200px" id="m1">
   <li>
     <a href="#">Item 1 </a>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li>
         <a href="#">Item 1A</a>
         <ul class="menu">
           <li><a href="#Item-1Aa">Item 1Aa</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Item-1Ba">Item 1Ba</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Item-1Ca">Item 1Ca</a></li> 
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#Item-1B">Item 1B</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Item-1C">Item 1C</a></li> 
     </ul>
  </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#">Item 2</a>
     <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="#Item-2A">Item 2A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-2B">Item 2B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Item-2C">Item 2C</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </li> 
  </ul>
```

The code doesn't mean much to you if you haven't used the drill dropdown foundation zurb plugin.

Comment: Your HTML at the top is invalid, beyond that it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Did you even use Foundation zurb?

Comment: I have used Foundation in the past, yes. The question is still unclear.

Comment: I need any button on click or hover to expand dropdown..

Comment: when I set that i lose my content dropdown...

Comment: You currently have the menu set up as a [drilldown menu](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/drilldown-menu.html), which does not behave like a standard dropdown menu. When you click on the parent item, the sub-menu will slide over the top of it.

Comment: Id suggest tidying your code

Comment: @APAD1 Yes I want drilldown menu...But drilldown on click button to show expand dropdown contetn

Comment: That's already how it works, as I mentioned before you click the parent menu button to expand the dropdown content.